# write to amazon aws dynamoDB with out a rang key

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-ios

I am expanding on exploring amazon's DynamoDB with `DynamoDBSample`, which they release recently with a bundle of libraries and frameworks called `awsiossdk v2`

So now the question is, if you go to the dynamoDB console on the web, `range key` is optional. So I have created one table with out `range key` only with `hash` but even though every thing look in place it still look for a `rang key` and app crashes.

One thing I suspect is that:

`AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];`

I am using `defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper` that probably mean hash and range. But I didn’t able to find any other property where the `dynamoDBObjectMapper` handle a db write with out a range key.

Appreciate it!

Additional Info.

[image: my table]

And here is how I am trying two write to it:

```
 AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSString *lat = [info objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *lon = [info objectForKey:@"lon"];
        NSMutableArray *geoLocationMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [geoLocationMutable addObject:lat];
        [geoLocationMutable addObject:lon];

        NSNCurrentStatusTable *currentStatusTableRow = [NSNCurrentStatusTable new];
        currentStatusTableRow.uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString];
        currentStatusTableRow.lastOnlineTime = [[info objectForKey:@"fullTimeNow"] substringFromIndex:2];
        currentStatusTableRow.geoLocation = geoLocationMutable;
        currentStatusTableRow.latitude = [info objectForKey:@"latNum"];
        currentStatusTableRow.longitude = [info objectForKey:@"lonNum"];
        [tasks addObject:[dynamoDBObjectMapper save:currentStatusTableRow]];
        [[BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks]
         continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
             if (task.error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
                 [self getNextStep:YES];
             }
             else
             {
                 [self getNextStep:YES];
             }
             return nil;
         }];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    });
});
```

Comment: You must give us more detail about the tables structure you are referring to / the code you use to query those tables. The Mapper works fine with tables without range keys. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @ChenHarel let me know if you need additional info

Comment: I'm sorry, you will have to wait for someone with iOS SDK knowledge